# Application rebrands - when should a branching strategy be employed?

Tags: java, git, branch, branching-and-merging, branding

**Note:** *In case it matters, we are using **git**, (so branching and merging is a breeze), and this is an Android application (**Java** - so conditional compilation is not really applicable).*

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381523/branching-strategy-for-configurable-software), but what if you have more than just UI differences between different rebrands of a single version of your software?  For example, what if an entire feature or subsystem should not be compiled into one of the rebrands (e.g. it contains code that is intellectual property of one company and should not be available to others)?

Should a separate branch be created for each rebrand in this case?  If so, is there any use for a main/master branch, since it will just become code-storage and not compile into any useful application (weird)?  But not having a main/master branch means having to cherry-pick (individually select) commits to merge across rebrands, which seems like a bad approach.

Or is there another way to solve this that doesn't involve branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information provided in Your question, I'd recomment not using branches.

Branches will divert unless merged. Therefore, making a bugfix available in all
branches will require a lot of cherry-picking or at least very careful commit/merge handling.

What about putting customer-specific code into libraries that are loaded by the application?

Pro:

- Only customer specific code gets duplicated.
- Generic code won't be forked for no reason.
- Generic code is coded against common interfaces.
- Customer specific application parts are only shipped to the corresponding customers.

Con:

- Careful design and life-cycle-management of common interfaces is required.
- Additional code for looking up and loading customer specific libraries. (not too difficult in Java or in the build process of Android)

Answer (score 2):

For real sensitive information/code issue, branches won't cut it:
You need to:

- isolate the sensitive code base into its own git repo
- reference it as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html)** for some of your projects
- don't reference it *at all* in the other projects which aren't supposed to see that code.

The idea is to make extra sure that no sensitive information will be pushed by mistake from one repo to another.

Comment: If customers need/have access to the repository, then I fully agree. If not, I do not see the requirement for different submodules as long as the build process picks only the libs for the current customer and do not include other customers' libs.

Comment: @Black way too risky for my taste. If the repo isn't *there*, you are *sure* the build process won't mess up.

Comment: @VonC I agree with both of you here - it was really difficult to choose between the two answers, they are both really good approaches.  In the end, we went with a separate repo, but didn't use submodules, instead we will, as Black suggests, leave some work for the build / deployment process. Thank you both.